# Fatal error: Class 'Connection' not found in D:\Projects\wamp\www\Session-6\classes\header.php on line 4

Tags: php, class, inheritance

Here I am trying to include a class file into another class file like

```
<?php
include './connection.php';
class header_class  extends connection
{

}
```

and in `connection.php`

```
<?php

class connection {
    //put your code here
}
```

both the files are in same folder called `classes`
now when i am trying to extend `connection` class in `header_class`.
Its give an fatal error.

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Connection' not found in D:\Projects\wamp\www\Session-6\classes\header.php on line 4
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  252240  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0008  267688  include( 'D:\Projects\wamp\www\Session-6\header.php' )  ..\index.php:8
3   0.0010  276552  include_once( 'D:\Projects\wamp\www\Session-6\classes\header.php' ) ..\header.php:2
```

i am quite surprised why it is happening..not only this but when i write `connection` class in same file as `header_class.php` ..Holaa its working..

please can anyone have idea why this is happening ?

**UPDATE :**
here i try something like create a subfolder in `classes` like `temp` put the `connection.php` file in it and then try to include its working !!!!!!!!!!!!! how ???

Comment: remove ./ from your include statement like this 
include 'connection.php';

Comment: not working..give the same error as preivous one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this `include './connection.php';` to `include 'connection.php';`
Replace you class name `connection` to `Connection`

Comment: @kishan please recheck your class name.

Comment: i try but vain.. i try with the class name as file name just like in java but still php refused to include :(

Comment: read the **update section** in my question if that was the issue then in that case its also not working..but its is working

Answer (score 0):

The reference path to any include file is referenced from your entry point. In your case, it is `index.php`.

So instead of including `connection.php`, you should include `classes/connection.php` to make it work.

P.S. If you follow [PSR4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), you can simply use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md) to auto load your class files. No need to deal with include path issue. Worth learning it.

Comment: but my index.php file include header.php and that header.php include connection php ..both (connection and header) are in same directory.. it is simple thing i try to include one php to another php..but not working with include statement

Comment: Your `index.php` is not in your `classes/` folder, unlike `header.php` and `connection.php`. Right?

Comment: As I descibed in my answer. If you're using relative path in `include` statement, the path will be resolved from the entry point (`index.php`) path. The location of `header.php` is irrelevant unless you're calling it directly.

Comment: ohk so what should i do to include that relative path ?

Comment: You can use absolute system path (e.g. `include "D:\Projects\wamp\www\Session-6\classes/connection.php"`). You can use PHP's [magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) to build the absolute path (e.g. `__DIR__`) so it is relative to the location of the include statement file (instead of entry point).

Comment: Still I recommend to use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) and its [spl_autloader](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) implementation. Much easier to maintain in long term.

Comment: yaah i will @koala Yeung its good to think about future scope as well

Answer (score 0):

You probably spelled *connection* wrong in " *extends connection* "...

Make sure your typing is correct, and make sure you **save** before testing your code..

Answer (score 0):

finally after googling i found this

```
include __DIR__. '/connection.php';
```

its working but don't why i need to append this  `__DIR__.` any idea ?

Comment: `__DIR__` is a [magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php). It is always the system path of the immediate script file. If you access the site from `/index.php`, includes a `/includes/header.php`, then run `echo __DIR__;` in the `header.php`, you'll get the system directory of `includes` folder. Therefore by prefixing the include path with `__DIR__`, it automatically build you the correct absolute path to `connection.php`, which is in the same folder of `header.php`.

Comment: i still surprise when i manually enter system directory then why it is refused to include..!! code is now working but i am like of stubborn people..so i try to find the exact reason @KoalaYeung

Comment: Do you understand my answer? What part do you think is still confusing?

Comment: yaah got is @KoalaYeung