# Class 'PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorage_CacheBase' not found in PHP

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I got Error while I was transferred my website to the new server.

I have import Data in Excel file using Php PHPExcel library but I have got the error.

Error Message:

> **Fatal error**:  Class
>   'PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorage_CacheBase' not found in
>   **/home/ndjnckfu/accounting.isplace.in/api/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/CachedObjectStorage/Memory.php**
>   on line **28**

Please send your thoughts below a comment.

Thank You.

Comment: Hey Please take a look on similar answer on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42336839/fatal-error-class-connection-not-found-in-d-projects-wamp-www-session-6-clas

Comment: @NiketJoshi You send that link does not match with my answer.